# Use Puppeteer Data in another File

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, async-await, puppeteer

```
async function get() {
  let url = `url`;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForSelector(".episode-title");

  const titlesFinal = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table tr td"));
    const rows = tds.map((td) => td.innerText);
    const rowsDate = rows.filter((text) => {
      if (text.includes(`/`)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    const rowsFinal = rowsDate.filter((text) => {
      if (text.includes(`New!`)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
        All;
      }
    });

    return rowsFinal;
  });

  const linksFinal = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table tr td a"));
    let arrayFinal = array.map((e) => e.href);

    return arrayFinal;
  });
  await browser.close();
}
```

How Do I use the Variables linksFinal and titlesFinal outside of the async function specifically in another JS file that has express.js where I already imported the is file!

- Disclaimer, I am Very New to Node and JS

Answer (score 1):

Go to your package.json and add on a new line.

```
"type": "module"
```

Then in your puppeteer you can return from the async function the values you need and export them by adding *export default* at the beginning of the function (or if you want make the function a const and then just *export const*).

In the file you want to use the data just import it like this.

```
import data from "what ever the path is to the datas file"
```